# Local path to JavaScript file are not working under loaded to WebBrowser control local HTML page

Tags: c#, javascript, wpf, xaml, browser

So I am loading local HTML file without any problem but JavaScripts are not working at all.

This html & JS has index.html that is loading to WebBrowser control.

```
<video width="640" height="360" style=" margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important;  overflow:hidden;"    id="player1" src="http://archive.bogi.ru/files/S2J4NW1xUVVqb2NKLWZINnE4bFFKb3VxY25TU1FsZWo5aTZpVlltWUk5R3lxSk5vCmllYWJiLVZ3LUZ0cTZ1UjRCYV9nUy1fbVMzMjQyblRhVHYxa2lB" type="video/mp4" > </video>


<script>
    MediaElement('player1', {
        success: function (me) {
            me.play();
        }
    }); </script>
```

Any clue how it could be fixed?

[image]

**P.S.** I have enabled this option:  **Internet Options > Advanced > Security > Allow active content to run in files on My Computer.**

Comment: how does it manifest "not working at all " ?

Comment: @Tigran Normally it should play video. But it doesn't. Pls have a look at my updated question.

Comment: @Tigran Also I am not sure if the path to JS files is a problem... Could it be some security issue that WebBrowser control doesn't load JS?

Comment: If you run the same code inside (say) Chrome, will it execute the stuff as it expected. ?

Comment: In this way you will erase doubts on if the *actually* code is broken or not ..

Comment: @Tigran Yes yes. It works perfect!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already had this problem(when you link to jquery file)

Instead of link to src to your jquery file copy jquery file content between this tag:

```
<script type="text/css">
//Copy First jquery content here
</script>
<script type="text/css">
//Copy secound jquery content here
</script>
.
.
.
```